# Json Object: linked list?

Tags: android, json

I have a Json string:

```
String json = "{\"I\":0,\"lst\":[{\"i1\":100500,\"s1\":\"abrakadabra\",
                        \"aList\":[{\"text\":\"secret will of my Dad\"}]}]}";
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(json);
```

My question: how, using  Json Obj methods, to browse through each node element recursively?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354546/recursively-parsing-json-via-jsonobject-to-fetch-value-against-specific-keys There is code at the bottom of that post.

Comment: Iterator<String> keys = json.sortedKeys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        // Note that "key" must be "1", "2", "3"...
        String key = keys.next();
        value = json.getJSONObject(key);
        <recursively call method using "value">

Comment: you meant that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitali, I don't have enough reputation points to reply to your comment, so posting it as an answer. In that post I linked, I meant the code snippet with loopThroughJson() method. I haven't tried it myself but that looks right. For completeness, this is the link again -

[Recursively parsing JSON via JSONObject to fetch value against specific keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354546/recursively-parsing-json-via-jsonobject-to-fetch-value-against-specific-keys)

Comment: Karthik VThank you!

Comment: Though it is ugly solution.. each time go through all object to find value of a key, so total (maximum) number of enumerations  is number of keys power 2. that's why I said about linked list

Comment: Json is bad solution

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the object, get child as reference of Object class using the `get()` method, if that object is instance of `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`, go deeper.